# add and get String Array into and from Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code that reads from XML file. It gets five strings (groupId, groupType, filePath, author, and lineNo), and it first saves them in a String Array. Then, the String Array is saved in an ArrayList. Finally, the last "for" displays the content of the ArrayList.

The problem that when I want to display the content, I get just the last added string array. The following is the code and the output. Can anyone figure out what is the problem?

```
ArrayList<String[]> developerTypes = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] developerInfo = {null, null, null, null, null};
String[] developerInfoR = {null, null, null, null, null};

String groupId;
String groupType;
String filePath;
String author;
String lineNo;


SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) builder.build("A.xml");
Element clones = doc.getRootElement();

// Loop of clones' children (clone_group)
List<Element> parentElements = clones.getChildren();
for(Element parentElement:parentElements){


    // Loop of clone_group's children (clone_fragment)
    List<Element> elements = parentElement.getChildren();
    for(Element element:elements){

        // Loop of clone_fragment's children (blameInfo)
        List<Element> childelements = element.getChildren();
        for(Element childElement:childelements){

            groupId = parentElement.getAttributeValue("groupid");
            groupType = parentElement.getAttributeValue("type");
            filePath = element.getAttributeValue("file");
            author = childElement.getAttributeValue("author");
            lineNo = childElement.getAttributeValue("lineNo");
            //System.out.print(groupId + " - ");
            //System.out.print(groupType + " - ");
            //System.out.print(file + " - ");
            //System.out.println(author);
            developerInfo[0] = groupId;
            developerInfo[1] = groupType;
            developerInfo[2] = filePath.substring(1, filePath.lastIndexOf("."));;
            developerInfo[3] = author;
            developerInfo[4] = lineNo;
            developerTypes.add(developerInfo);

        }// for (blameInfo)    
    }// for (clone_fragment)
}// for (clone_group)

// Display the content of the Arraylist    
for(int i = 0; i< developerTypes.size(); ++i){

    developerInfoR = developerTypes.get(i);

    for(int j = 0; j< developerInfoR.length; ++j){

        System.out.print(developerInfoR[j] + " ");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

The Output:

```
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
309 Type-3 builtin/update-index.c Jonathan Nieder 704 
...
```

Comment: Seems to me you need to know how to handle a good IDE with debugger, the error will become quickly apparent when you "step through" code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem that when I want to display the content, I get just the last added string array.

No, you find that you've got *many* references to the *same* string array... because that's what you've added. You've only got one string array *object*; `developerInfo` is just a reference to that array. When you call `developerTypes.add(developerInfo)` that's copying the reference into the `ArrayList`, so you've got the same reference lots of times.

You should pull the declaration and instantiation of `developerInfo` into the loop:

```
String[] developerInfo = {
    groupId,
    groupType,
    filePath.substring(1, filePath.lastIndexOf(".")),
    author,
    lineNo
};
developerTypes.add(developerInfo);
```

Likewise your code would be cleaner if you didn't declare `developerInfoR` until you used it:

```
for(int i = 0; i< developerTypes.size(); ++i){
    String[] developerInfoR = developerTypes.get(i);
    for(int j = 0; j< developerInfoR.length; ++j){
        System.out.print(developerInfoR[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Or even better, use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (String[] developerInfoR : developerTypes) {
    for (String info : developerInfoR) {
        System.out.print(info + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

*In general*, you should declare local variables with the smallest scope you can get away with, as late as possible, ideally assigning a value at the point of declaration. Declaring all the variables at the top of the method really hurts readability.

Comment: It also makes it really easy to identify C programmers.

Comment: @Charles Not any C programmers, mind you, but K&R-style C programmers :)

Answer (score 2):

You have only one instance of the `developerInfo` array that you keep adding over and over in the loop. You need to make a new array in each loop step.

You seem to have some misunderstanding of the semantics of the contsructs you are using. I'm deducing that from the way you are initializing `developerInfoR` up front, but never using that value. An array variable only contains a reference to the array, so every time you assign to it, the array referenced before gets forgotten and thrown away. So, don't initialize `developerInfo` up front. In fact, you don't even need to declare it until the place you are using it.

There is also a simpler way to print an array's contents: just call `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(developerInfoR))`. That way you don't even need the inner loop in the printing code.

You don't need any of the variables groupId, groupType, filePath, author, lineNo. Just write for example `developerInfo[0] = parentElement.getAttributeValue("groupid");` and similar. That makes for more obvious code. But it will probably make sense to use a full object instead of a String[]. There are many fields and the meaning of each gets behind the integer index.

All in all, taking these suggestions plus a few additional ones, your code can be rewritten to this:

```
final String path = filePath.substring(1, filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
final Document doc = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build("A.xml");
final List<DeveloperInfo> developers = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (Element parentElement : doc.getRootElement().getChildren())
  for (Element element : parentElement.getChildren())
    for (Element childElement : element.getChildren())
      developers.add(new DeveloperInfo(
          parentElement.getAttributeValue("groupid"),
          parentElement.getAttributeValue("type"),
          element.getAttributeValue("file"),
          path,
          childElement.getAttributeValue("author"),
          childElement.getAttributeValue("lineNo"),
      ));
for (DeveloperInfo d : developerTypes) System.out.println(d);
```

The DeveloperInfo class:

```
class DeveloperInfo {
  public final String groupId, groupType, filePath, author, lineNo;
  public DeveloperInfo(
      String groupId, String groupType, String filePath, 
      String author, String lineNo)
  {
    this.groupId = groupId; this.groupType = groupType; this.filePath = filePath;
    this.author = author; this.lineNo = lineNo;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "DeveloperInfo [groupId=" + groupId + ", groupType=" + groupType + 
      ", filePath=" + filePath + ", author=" + author + ", lineNo=" + lineNo + "]";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same array every time you add it to the `ArrayList`.

Instead of declaring this `String[] developerInfo = {null, null, null, null, null};`

at the beginning. Create a new array everytime you loop.

`String[] developerInfo = new String[5];`